# Convert Image to numpy Array (image classification)

Tags: python, image, keras, artificial-intelligence, classification

I'm following this tutorial: [How do I load train and test data from the local drive for a deep learning Keras model?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-load-train-and-test-data-from-the-local-drive-for-a-deep-learning-Keras-model) and it went like this 
`name 'train_data' is not defined`
I know I haven't defined train_data yet, but I don't know what to write inside train_data = ...

My code is look like this

```
train_path = '/Users/nayageovani/Documents/Artificial Intelligence/dataset/train'
train_batch = os.listdir(train_path)
x_train = []

# if data are in form of images
for sample in train_data:
    img_path = train_path+sample
    x = image.load_img(img_path)
    # preprocessing if required
    x_train.append(x)
test_path = PATH+'/data/test/'
test_batch = os.listdir(test_path)
x_test = []
```

heres my folder of dataset looks like

```
|--dataset
  |--test
     |--fresh
     |--rotten
  |--train
     |--fresh
     |--rotten
```

Comment: What's your code look like?

Comment: i updated it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`train_data` (and `test_data` ) should be iterables that contain the file names of your training or test data, respectively.

You could, for example, create a list of files in the training data directory like:

```
import os
...

imgTypes = ['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp']
train_data = [item for item in os.listdir(train_path) if \
        (os.path.isfile(os.path.join(train_path, item)) and
            os.path.splitext(item)[1].lower() in imgTypes)]
```

## Update:

A better alternative for loading the image data is using [keras' `ImageDataGenerator` class](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/). Among other things, it directly allows you to preprocess your data while loading.

Comment: i tried and got module 'posixpath' has no attribute 'listdir' :(

Comment: @NayaGeovani: Sorry, my mistake: the function is in the `os`-module directly and not in the `os.path` submodule (updated the code above).

Comment: i dont know whats this mean No such file or directory: '/Users/nayageovani/Documents/Artificial Intelligence/dataset/train.DS_Store'

Comment: @NayaGeovani: You are trying to load the quoted file, which doesn't exist on your disk. Create a list of images you want to load as training data. Use the code I posted as example. Take care to only load image data, you could for example check the file ending for this.

Comment: @NayaGeovani: The exact error you posted is caused by appending the path with the `+`-operator in that  line: `img_path = train_path+sample` (a slash is missing in the resulting path between `train` and `.DS_Store`. Use `os.path.join` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) for a more robust way of assembling path strings.

Comment: i dont understand, i already separated all of my images into 2 classes (fresh and rotten) inside the train folder

Comment: Can you describe more precisely what you do not understand?

Comment: like this? img_path = train_path(os.path.join(sample))

Comment: @NayaGeovani: Like `img_ = os.path.join(train_path, sample)`

Comment: it says `cannot identify image file '/Users/nayageovani/Documents/Artificial Intelligence/dataset/train/.DS_Store`

Comment: @NayaGeovani: Because it is not an image file. As I wrote in a previous comment: you have to filter for image files. You could do that by checking the file extension.

Comment: @NayaGeovani: I updated the code I posted with an example for filtering by file extension.

Comment: i need your help..  i tried to print the x_train size and why its 0? i expected it shows how many image in my folder,is it bcs my train folder contain fresh and rotten whichs not a jpg? or what?

Comment: @NayaGeovani: That is hard to answer without seeing the complete code. What format/ file extension do your images have?

Comment: @NayaGeovani: I think I saw the problem. Your `train` directory only contains two sub-directories `fresh` and `rotten`? Then you should load the images from those sub-directories (adapt train_path) and mix them. Please keep in mind that your training data should include samples from both classes!

Comment: you mean by mix them is not to separate the fresh and rotten image?

Comment: @NayaGeovani: Yes, for training a classification model it is essential, that all cases are contained in the training data.